# show that $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_{2020}^2\geqslant x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_{2020}x_1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

how can i use AM-GM inequality to show that $$x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_{2020}^2\geqslant x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_{2020}x_1 ?$$
Where $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ 
are any real numbers.

to get an idea I tried to do for particular cases with $n=3,4.$

for $n=3$, I could use AM-GM doing $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}+\frac{x_2^2+x_3^2}{2}+\frac{x_3^2+x_1^2}{2}\geqslant x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1.$$
for $n=4$  couldn't with that same idea. 
but it is possible to show 
developing the inequality below $$(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(x_3-x_4)^2+(x_4-x_1)^2 \geqslant 0.$$

Comment: "for $n=4$ couldn't with that same idea." Why?

Comment: If they are real numbers they can be negative . How will you apply AM-GM if that's the case?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar AM-GM Inequality still holds if $n$ is even. We can simply replace each $x_i$ with $|x_i|$.

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz will do it to, if you write it as $\big \vert \mathbf x \big(P \mathbf x\big)\big \vert \leq \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert \big \Vert P\mathbf x\big \Vert  = \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert^2$ with $P:=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 &0 & \cdots &0  & 1\\ 
1 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0  & 0\\ 
0 & 1 &0 & \cdots &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 0 &1& \cdots &0  & 0\\ 
0 & 0 &0& \ddots &0  & 0\\ 
0 & 0 &0& \cdots &1  & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is the same:
$$
x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + \cdots + x_{2020}x_1 \leq \frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{2} + \frac{x_2^2 + x_3^2}{2} + \cdots + \frac{x_{2020}^2 + x_1^2}{2} = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_{2020}^2
$$

Comment: Suppose for all odd i $x_i<0$ then lhs will be negative and rha which is sum of squares will be positive that's an obstacle which needs to be tackled.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar That's no issue, since $x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + \cdots + x_{2020}x_1 \leq |x_1||x_2| + |x_2||x_3| + \cdots + |x_{2020}||x_1|$.

Comment: Yeah that will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_{n+1}=x_1.$ We have $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_{i+1}=$$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1}{2}(x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2)-\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_{i+1}=$$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {1}{2}(x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2-2x_ix_{i+1})=$$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {1}{2}(x_i-x_{i+1})^2\ge 0.$$ See " Cauchy-Schwartz inequality " in Wikipedia. In the notation of that article, this Q is a special case with $u=(x_1,...,x_n)\in \Bbb R^n$ and $v=(x_2,...,x_{n+1})\in \Bbb R^n$ with $x_{n+1}=x_1. $

BTW. In $\Bbb R^m,$ with $m\ge 2,$ define the distance from  $A=(a_1,...,a_m)$ to $B=(b_1,...,b_m)$  as $AB=(\sum_{i=1}^m(a_i-b_i)^2)^{1/2}.$ Now take any two vectors $A,B \in \Bbb R^m,$ neither of them equal to the origin $O,$ and neither of them a scalar (real-number) multiple of the other. Then the $2$-dimensional vector subspace generated by $A$ and $B$ is geometrically isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2,$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^ma_ib_i=AO\cdot BO\cdot \cos \angle AOB.$$